# How to make a background animation into a loop (repeat function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, repeat

I have a script showing starts on the background of the website. It stops after a while. How can I make it into a loop?

```
$(function(){
  $('#midground').css({backgroundPosition: '0px 0px'});
  $('#foreground').css({backgroundPosition: '0px 0px'});

  $('#midground').animate({
    backgroundPosition:"(-10000px -2000px)"
  }, 240000, 'linear');

  $('#foreground').animate({
    backgroundPosition:"(-10000px -2000px)"
  }, 180000, 'linear');
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Stick it in a function then call itself after a setTimeout.

```
function myAnimation() {
    $('#midground').css({backgroundPosition: '0px 0px'});
    $('#foreground').css({backgroundPosition: '0px 0px'});

        $('#midground').animate({
            backgroundPosition:"(-10000px -2000px)"
        }, 240000, 'linear');

        $('#foreground').animate({
            backgroundPosition:"(-10000px -2000px)"
        }, 180000, 'linear', function() {
            setTimeout(myAnimation, 500);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes though with those extremely long animation delays it'd probably be best to call "setTimeout()" from inside the completion callback from one of those.

Comment: True. And depending on if OP wants the animations to happen asynchronously, he may want to set the second `animate` as the callback for the first.

Comment: Great, that worked. With a little tweaking I got them both in a loop. Thanks Neurotrace

Comment: Not a problem, I'm glad that worked out for you. If that answered your question then I wouldn't mind at all if you accepted my answer ;)